# Get parent VALUE on React-select grouped options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Im using react-select with grouped options, they are grouped like this:

```
{
  label: PARENT_NAME,
  value: PARENT_ID,
  options: [
    {
      label: CHILD_NAME,
      value: CHILD_ID,
    }
  ]
}
```

I have an array with those options, and im passing it to the  component like this:

```
<Select
  options={ARR_OF_OPTIONS}
  onChange={this.handleChange("name")}
/>
```

My handleChange function is like this:

```
handleChange = name => selectedOption => {
  const value = selectedOption.value
  this.setState({ [name]: value, })
}
```

**My question is:**
Is it possible to get the PARENT_ID when selecting the child option?

Hopefully I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Help me understand your code. Are you doing something like this `<Select options={group1.options} onChange={this.handleChange(group1.label)} />` ?

Comment: @chiragrtr no, the component <Select> will get the all the options that are grouped in the first part of the code. The onChange im passing the name of the <Select> to update the state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every option can have more properties

```
{
  label: PARENT_NAME,
  value: PARENT_ID,
  options: [
    {
      label: CHILD_NAME,
      value: CHILD_ID,

      // additional properties
      group: PARENT_ID,
      otherValue: OTHER_VALUE,
    }
  ]
}
```

`selectedOption` is an object - you can easily access `group`, `otherValue`

```
handleChange = name => selectedOption => {
  const value = selectedOption.value
  console.log("group", selectedOption.group )
  this.setState({ [name]: value, })
}
```

This method (based on original react-select grouped example) duplicates data (in this case) but is safe for case when value can exists in multiple groups (can't be reliably found by comparing value).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with pure JavaScript. On your handleChange method, you should filter out the grouped object from `ARR_OF_OPTIONS` that contains the selected child option.

```
const selectedParent = ARR_OF_OPTIONS
  .find((group) => group.options.find(({ value }) => value === selectedOption.value));

const { value } = selectedParent;  // this gives you the parent id
```